# Bootstrap 4 card-deck column count and correctly set margin first and last item

Tags: sass, twitter-bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4. And I am using SCSS / SASS.

1. How do I correctly specify the number of columns for my card-deck? I want e.g. 3 columns.
2. And then how to I correctly set the margin for the *first* and *last* `card`? So the first `card` has no left-margin and the *last* card has no right-margin?

Because now it's not aligned correctly. See image.

[image]

This is my markup:

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title 1</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title 2</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title 3</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title 4</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title 5</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title 6</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the flexbox of `.card-deck` and `.card`.
If you see the `.card` inside `.card-deck` has  `flex: 1 0 0%;`
We need to overwrite that rule and take advantage of **flex-basis**. We also need to overwrite the margins. How I did it with sass:

HTML:

```
 <div class="card-deck justify-content-between" id="card-deck">
     <div class="card">
         <div class="card-block">
             <h4 class="card-title">Card title 1</h4>
             <p class="card-text">This is a text</p>
         </div>
     </div>
    ...
 </div>
```

scss:

```
 $cols: ( sm: 2, md: 3, lg: 4, xl: 6 ) !default;

 #custom-card-deck .card {
     margin: 0 0 $spacer 0;

     @each $breakpoint in map-keys($cols) {
         @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
             $col: map-get($cols, $breakpoint);

             flex: 0 0 calc(#{percentage(1/$col)} - #{$spacer * ($col - 1)/ $col});
         }
     }
 }
```

where `$cols` are the columns for each breakpoint.

Cards get default size from flex-basis, 'no grow' and 'no shrink' using shorthand (flex: 'flex-grow' 'flex-shrink' 'flex-basis'). On parent element (`.card-deck`) add `.justify-content-between` to distribute the extra space in between the cards.

Everything about flexbox I read from this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).